# PDF parsing in Apache TIKA

Tags: scala, parsing, apache-tika, pdf-parsing

I am very new to Apache Tika and trying to figure it out on how to use it. I read some blogs over internet and was trying to parse a PDF file. My Scala Code is:

```
import java.io.{File,FileInputStream}

import org.apache.tika.Tika
import org.apache.tika.parser._
import org.apache.tika.metadata._
import org.apache.tika.sax.WriteOutContentHandler
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser

object TikaExtract extends App{
  val tika = new Tika()

  val file1 = new File("/home/user/Documents/aa.pdf")
  val stream = new FileInputStream(file1)

  val pdf = new PDFParser()
  val handler = new WriteOutContentHandler(-1)
  val metadata = new Metadata()
  val context = new ParseContext()
  pdf.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context)
  stream.close()
}
```

Error I am getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jempbox/xmp/XMPSchema at TikaExtract$.delayedEndpoint$TikaExtract$1(TikaExtract.scala:15) at TikaExtract$delayedInit$body.apply(TikaExtract.scala:9) at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34) at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12) at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76) at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76) at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35) at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76) at TikaExtract$.main(TikaExtract.scala:9) at TikaExtract.main(TikaExtract.scala) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jempbox.xmp.XMPSchema at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 11 more

What wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Something is wrong with your runtime environment.  Can you post details about how you are building and running your code?

Comment: I have downloaded Apache Tika jars from Maven Repository (1.17) and have added them as External Jars to Scala IDE. Running program from Scala IDE as well.

Comment: Adding only Tika's jars to the classpath is not enough, because they have their own dependencies. As you may see, [Apache Jempbox](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/jempbox/usages) is used by Tika, so it also has to be on the class path. A better choice to solve it would be to use a build tool (e.g. SBT for Scala projects) and Tika as a library dependency: that will automatically drop in all other transitive dependencies that it needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any page or blog where it’s explained how to do that to setup proper environment for running Tika programs?